# Пунктуация в приведённом предложении

Tags: пунктуация, предлоги

Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении?

*Благодаря хорошей погоде и шумной компании(,) черноморские летние каникулы стали самым ярким событием.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Благодаря хорошей погоде и шумной компании черноморские летние каникулы стали самым ярким событием.***

Запятая не нужна. Обстоятельственный оборот с предлогом ***благодаря*** стоит в начале предложения, не разделяет подлежащее и сказуемое. Обособление было бы необходимо при такой структуре предложения:

*Черноморские летние каникулы, благодаря хорошей погоде и шумной компании, стали самым ярким событием.*

См. [**ПУНКТУАЦИЯ ПРИ ОБОРОТАХ С НЕПЕРВООБРАЗНЫМИ ПРЕДЛОГАМИ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1)

Answer (score 0):

Запятая ставится с «благодаря», если это деепричастие. С сочетаниями, где «благодаря» — предлог причины, запятая не ставится. В данном примере это предлог.